# Ошибка 1619 при удаленной установки приложений msi. C# console

Tags: c#, консоль

Пробую установить приложения на удаленном компьютере: 
Если установочные файлы находятся на локальном диске, то установка проходит успешно.
Если установочные файлы находятся на сетевом диске, то выдает ошибку 1619 "This installation package could not be opened, please verify that it is accessible."

Доступ к сетевому диску у меня есть и у пользователя на удаленном компьютере тоже. В чем проблема? Где я ошибся?

```
using CredentialManagement;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] app = { "1.msi", "2.msi", "3.msi" };
            string retVal = "";

            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            string targetIpAddress = "targetPC";   // you can change this target IP address
            options.Username = @"domain\username";
            options.Password = "password";
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(("\\\\" + targetIpAddress + "\\root\\cimv2"), options);
            scope.Connect();

            ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("Win32_Product");
            ManagementClass classInstance = new ManagementClass(scope, p, null);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("Install");
            ManagementBaseObject outParams;
            inParams["AllUsers"] = true;
            inParams["Options"] = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in app)
            {
                inParams["PackageLocation"] = @"\\network_drive\app_location" + item;
                outParams = classInstance.InvokeMethod("Install", inParams, null);
                retVal = outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString();

                retVal_install(app, inParams, retVal, item);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static void retVal_install(string[] _app, ManagementBaseObject _inParams, string _retVal, string _item)
        {
            switch (_retVal)
            {
                case "0":

                    Console.WriteLine("The installation " + _item + " completed successfully.");

                    break;

                case "2":

                    Console.WriteLine("The system cannot find the specified file. \n\r\n\r" + _inParams["PackageLocation"]);

                    break;

                case "3":

                    Console.WriteLine("The system cannot find the path specified. \n\r\n\r" + _inParams["PackageLocation"]);

                    break;

                case "1619":

                    Console.WriteLine("This installation package \n\r\n\r " + _inParams["PackageLocation"] + "\n\r\n\rcould not be opened, please verify that it is accessible.");

                    break;

                case "1620":

                    Console.WriteLine("This installation package \n\r\n\r " + _inParams["PackageLocation"] + "\n\r\n\rcould not be opened, please verify that it is a valid MSI package.");

                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(_retVal);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, решение в лоб: Что вам мешает локально скачать пакет во временную папку и запустить?

Comment: Не нашел действенного способа копировать папки с файлами и подпапками целиком на локальный диск с сетевого (какой-нибудь файл в подпапке или подпапка пропадут). Если у вас есть решение этой проблемы буду рад попробовать.

Comment: Ну простая рекурсия. На msdn есть пример через стек.

Comment: [это?](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories)

Comment: спасибо, сработало (скопировалось все целиком)